# innerHTML function called doesn't reflect changes to data on click

Tags: javascript

I have a button loads HTML into a div on click using an innerHTML function.  The first time I click, it loads the HTML correctly, but if I change the data source, none of these changes are reflected when I click the button again.  It just reloads the HTML that was accurate the first time that the button was clicked.  Refreshing page doesn't help. How do I get it to correctly call the current data source on each click?

button:

```
<li><button onclick="load_bookings();">Bookings</button></li>
```

function:

```
function load_bookings() {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="bookings_home.html" height=100% width=100%></object>';
    }
```

Comment: How exactly are you changing the data source? By manually editing the `data` attribute through the F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: What do you mean by *"..change the data source"*, how exactly do you do that ?

Comment: in reply to Obsidian and adeneo - by "change the data source" I mean, I edit the booking_home.html file.  Those edits aren't reflected when I click the button that loads it, nor when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

What it *appears* you are doing is loading a page in an `object` tag, which is pretty unusual to start. The problem I think you are having is the file `bookings_home.html` is requested via GET request, and gets cached. If you want a new version of that file, you would need to add a "cache-buster" parameter for the URL/file name:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="bookings_home.html?_=' + Date.now() + '" height=100% width=100%></object>';
```

Of course, is is preferable to use `document.createElement()` for adding markup to the page.

- [MDN - Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: Ok - I will try using document.createElement() and post results.  The fact that I have been using the wrong type of java function is probably why I haven't found many posts about this!

Answer (score -1):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<ul>
    <li><button onclick="load_bookings();">Bookings</button></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    function load_bookings() {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="bookings_home.html" height="100%" width="100%"></object>';
    }
</script>
```

bookings_home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div id="some"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('some').innerHTML = String(Math.random());
</script>
```

I tested it locally. Everything works fine.
Also, pay attention to the *caching* (answer of **Sam R**).